# How to calculate difference between the dates in PHP?

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

How to calculate difference between the dates?

Is there any default function for to calculate the date differences?..

Thanks

Ravi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[date_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)

example:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = date("Y/m/d");
$comp_date = "2010/12/1";

if($date1 <= $comp_date)//-------- if for date is less than limit

{

}

else if($date1 > $comp_date)//---------ElseIf for date is greator than limit                      

{


}//----End else if($date1 > $comp_date)

}//--------- End Main if
```

You can try this method too...